# Graphite Returns All values, rather than function

Tags: graphite

Suppose I have the following query:

```
http:/graphite.server:####/render?&target=highestCurrent(metric.path.value,3)
```

I am running into the issue that graphite is returning all values in the metric, rather than the last three "highest current".

I am having trouble finding an example that is end to end.  Typically, they consist of only: `&target=...`, and so I assume that this is just "supposed to work."

What could be a possible source of the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is supposed to draw all values of the 3 highest metrics/series. Not 3 metrics from of one series.

highestCurrent(seriesList, n)

```
Takes one metric or a wildcard seriesList followed by an integer N. Out of all metrics passed, draws only the N metrics with the highest value at the end of the time period specified.

Example:

&target=highestCurrent(server*.instance*.threads.busy,5)

Draws the 5 servers with the highest busy threads.
```

Comment: the "takes one metric" component implies an elementwise operation, and is the contradiction, as the function does nothing to only one time series. Why would one have a function accept a parameter it does nothing to, when an equivalently named function could operate elementwise, rather than row wise?  Plus, it has to check for the highest current on a per-metric basis anyways, so you are committing to unnecessary compute and transmit with the call...